# Where does gnome-clocks store the alarms?

Tags: gnome-clocks

I am using gnome-clocks but I am unable to find out where it stores the created alarms? What file/location are these stored on Ubuntu?

Comment: [stored here](https://newbedev.com/where-are-gnome-terminal-profiles-stored-in-the-filesystem)

Answer (score 0):

via gsettings, run below command

```
gsettings get org.gnome.clocks alarms
```

Example:

```
[admin@ANTARCTICA ~]$ gsettings get org.gnome.clocks alarms
[{'name': <'PRATAP_GNOME_CLOCKS'>, 'id': <'dc2758bc7809665555c59dfe62b48bc1'>, 'active': <true>, 'hour': <21>, 'minute': <32>, 'days': <[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]>, 'snooze_minutes': <10>, 'ring_minutes': <5>}]
```

via dconf, run below command

```
dconf read /org/gnome/clocks/alarms
```

Example:

```
[admin@ANTARCTICA ~]$ dconf read /org/gnome/clocks/alarms
[{'name': <'PRATAP_GNOME_CLOCKS'>, 'id': <'dc2758bc7809665555c59dfe62b48bc1'>, 'active': <true>, 'hour': <21>, 'minute': <32>, 'days': <[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]>, 'snooze_minutes': <10>, 'ring_minutes': <5>}]
```

Where does GSettings store its files https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8922/383311